# libreoffice crashing with signal 11

Tags: libreoffice, crash

I cannot start libreoffice anymore. (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS)
The error persists after reinstalling entire libreoffice.

I get the following error:

```
Fatal exception: Signal 11

Stack:

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x3e023)[0x7fa7491e6023]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x3e19a)[0x7fa7491e619a]

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x46210)[0x7fa748fd3210]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_cppu.so.3(+0x16e07)[0x7fa74724de07]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_cppu.so.3(uno_type_any_assign+0x93)[0x7fa74724d233]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(+0x2849ec1)[0x7fa74ba51ec1]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(+0x284a3fa)[0x7fa74ba523fa]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN3utl10ConfigItemC2ERKN3rtl8OUStringE14ConfigItemMode+0x82)[0x7fa74ba4c102]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(+0x2884526)[0x7fa74ba8c526]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN19SvtSysLocaleOptionsC1Ev+0x129)[0x7fa74ba8d9c9]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_Z7InitVCLv+0x1b0)[0x7fa74be6d0a0]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_Z10ImplSVMainv+0x115)[0x7fa74be6e675]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(soffice_main+0xa3)[0x7fa74afb3663]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin(+0x10b0)[0x5563290400b0]

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7fa748fb40b3]

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin(+0x10ee)[0x5563290400ee]
```

```
rc  gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1                         1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        GTK3 widget wrapping LibreOffice functionality - introspection
ii  libjuh-java                                   1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- Java Uno helper
ii  libjurt-java                                  1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- Java Uno Runtime
rc  liblibreofficekitgtk                          1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        GTK3 widget wrapping LibreOffice functionality
ii  libreoffice                                   1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite (metapackage)
ii  libreoffice-base                              1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- database
ii  libreoffice-base-core                         1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- shared library
ii  libreoffice-base-drivers                      1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        Database connectivity drivers for LibreOffice
ii  libreoffice-calc                              1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- spreadsheet
ii  libreoffice-common                            1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- arch-independent files
ii  libreoffice-core                              1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- arch-dependent files
ii  libreoffice-draw                              1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- drawing
ii  libreoffice-gnome                             1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- GNOME integration
ii  libreoffice-gtk3                              1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- GTK+ 3 integration
rc  libreoffice-help-common                       1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- common files for LibreOffice help
rc  libreoffice-help-en-gb                        1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- English_british help
rc  libreoffice-help-en-us                        1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- English_american help
ii  libreoffice-impress                           1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- presentation
ii  libreoffice-java-common                       1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- arch-independent Java support files
rc  libreoffice-l10n-en-gb                        1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- English_british language package
rc  libreoffice-l10n-en-za                        1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- English_southafrican language package
ii  libreoffice-math                              1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- equation editor
ii  libreoffice-nlpsolver                         0.9+LibO6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1        all          "Solver for Nonlinear Programming" extension for LibreOffice
ii  libreoffice-report-builder                    1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          LibreOffice component for building database reports
ii  libreoffice-report-builder-bin                1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        LibreOffice component for building database reports -- libraries
ii  libreoffice-script-provider-bsh               1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          BeanShell script support provider for LibreOffice scripting framework
ii  libreoffice-script-provider-js                1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          JavaScript script support provider for LibreOffice scripting framework
ii  libreoffice-script-provider-python            1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          Python script support provider for LibreOffice scripting framework
ii  libreoffice-sdbc-firebird                     1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        Firebird SDBC driver for LibreOffice
ii  libreoffice-sdbc-mysql                        1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        MariaDB/MySQL SDBC driver for LibreOffice
ii  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql                   1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        PostgreSQL SDBC driver for LibreOffice
rc  libreoffice-style-breeze                      1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- Breeze symbol style
ii  libreoffice-style-colibre                     1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- colibre symbol style
ii  libreoffice-style-elementary                  1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- Elementary symbol style
ii  libreoffice-style-tango                       1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- Tango symbol style
ii  libreoffice-wiki-publisher                    1.2.0+LibO6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1      all          LibreOffice extension for working with MediaWiki articles
ii  libreoffice-writer                            1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- word processor
rc  libreofficekit-data                           1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          common data for LOKDocView
ii  libridl-java                                  1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- base types and types access library for the Java Uno typesystem
ii  libuno-cppu3                                  1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- CPPU public library
ii  libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3                       1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- CPPU helper library
ii  libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3                    1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- "purpose environment" helper
ii  libuno-sal3                                   1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- SAL public library
ii  libuno-salhelpergcc3-3                        1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- SAL helpers for C++ library
ii  libunoil-java                                 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- UNO interface library
ii  libunoloader-java                             1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- (Java) UNO loader
ii  mythes-en-us                                  1:6.4.3-1                             all          English (USA) Thesaurus for LibreOffice
ii  uno-libs-private                              1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- private libraries used by public ones
ii  ure                                           1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        LibreOffice UNO runtime environment
```

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i libreoffice` to the question.

Comment: I just could start libreoffice as another user! A dialog asked about restore, I clicked no restore and LO was there. But the error persists for me as a user.

Comment: I just moved .config/libreoffice and voilà, lo starts again. But when I switch back, it crashes again. There is probably the left overs of a failed file loading (I had a problem with a very large file).

Comment: I did a diff of .config/libreoffice/4/user, the new one created by LO and the one that leads to crash. If anyone interested, I can send the file (can't post it, too long). I think this error is just for LO developers.